# ServiceActivator for container managed clustering using jgroups : org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceActivator: Provider class not found error

Tags: deployment, jboss, classloader, ear, jgroups

I am trying to use a service activator for jgroups channel.
I have put a file called : org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceActivator
in META-INF/services/
the content of the file is something like com.blahblah.project.cluster.JGroupsServiceActivator
which is the actual location of existence of the JGroupsServiceActivator file.

My deployment is an ear package which has a jar and a war file within. However when I try to deploy my application, I keep getting the following error:

```
11:45:52,222 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."proj-ear.ear"."proj-ejb-0.61.1-SNAPSHOT.jar".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."proj-ear.ear"."proj-ejb-0.61.1-SNAPSHOT.jar".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "proj-ejb-0.61.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" of deployment "proj-ear.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceActivator: Provider com.blahblah.proj.cluster.JGroupsServiceActivator not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:231) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:181) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:365) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.service.ServiceActivatorProcessor.deploy(ServiceActivatorProcessor.java:60) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    ... 5 more

11:45:52,419 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."proj-ear.ear"."proj-ejb-0.61.1-SNAPSHOT.jar".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."proj-ear.ear"."proj-ejb-0.61.1-SNAPSHOT.jar".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "proj-ejb-0.61.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" of deployment "proj-ear.ear"
```

It does not find the provider. Is there any idea why? Here JgroupsServiceActivator is my own class within the jar.
How can I make this file explicitly visible to jboss?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a dependency to `org.jboss.as.server` in the project manifest (`war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`).

Answer (score 0):

it's similar to gcvt's answer but that's what solved the problem for me - adding dependency module 'org.jboss.as.server' to jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.jgroups"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups"/>
        <module name="org.infinispan"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.server"/>
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```